# URL Rewrite Management showing thousands of auto generated re-directs

Tags: magento-1.8, url, url-rewrite

I've just started a new job with a company who are using Magento for their ecommerce store (ver. 1.8.1.0)

I've noticed in their Google Analytics account that they have traffic hitting what looks like a ton of duplicate product pages. The urls look like this:

> /productA-name.html
>   /productA-name-218.html
>   /productA-name-214.html
>   /sub-category/productA-name-214.html
>   etc

For just one of our product pages, there are 50 of these pages being reported in Google Analytics over a 8 month period.

Now I'm only just getting to grips with Magento, but I decided to look in there to see if I could find anything that looked out of place.

Under Catalog > URL Rewrite management there are a total of 40986 records found. 
Most of these seem to be autogenerated and are product pages with these sequential numbers redirecting to each other.

i.e.

> /productA-name-218.html to /productA-name-219.html
>   /productA-name-217.html to /productA-name-218.html

The site was launched in October of last year and we have just under 400 product lines.

I'm guessing this is not supposed to be happening.
Also would these 40k redirects have a negative impact on the speed performance of our website?

Could really do with knowing if this is a big issue for us and if possible is there an easy fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate the core_rewrite table to start and then review [this](http://www.adurolabs.com/blog/technical/how-to-add-rel-canonical-in-magento) article to use canonical URLs for your store.

To enable them for products and categories go to System > Configuration > Catalog and then click on the option labelled “Search Engine Optimizations”.